# How to remove header on a certain page

Tags: header-footer

I've written a synopsis section for each chapter of my thesis, and I've noticed a minor issue. Since the synopsis section comes *before* the `\chapter` its header is from the last section of the previous chapter. Is there a simple fix to either remove the header for this page only or replace the header with something like `Synopsis: Chapter X`?

[image]

I've include some code below.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\blinddocument

\newpage
\begin{center} 
{\bf Synopsis: Chapter 2} 
\end{center}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the downvote!? I'm new to this site and I'm trying my best!

Comment: @xport: If you downvoted this and the previous question by the same user, pleaser reconsider your downvoting strategy. As I commented on the other question, downvotes on this site are rare and commonly only used for bad/wrong things. I for one would be happy if it could stay that way. If you didn't issue the downvote, apologies for the false assumption.

Comment: @xport: Since the code is trimmed now, I guess you can undo the downvote? Also please remember to use @username to notify users other than the original author of your comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try it this way:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{Synopsis: Chapter 2} 
\blindtext
\clearpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a stylistic alternative, rather than a technical means of doing what you currently need, you might want to consider this:

```
\chapter{...}
<<synopsis>>
\clearpage (or other form of separation, such as a horizontal rule,
or putting the synopsis in a box, or making the synopsis the first \section)
<<chapter content>>
```

My reasoning behind this suggestion is that it places the synopsis *inside* the context of the chapter, so that the reader sees the chapter title *before* reading the synopsis.

Clearly, one's mileage may vary...